# Return specific object value in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, unit-testing, object, methods

I want to check for specific console logs during my tests with

```
it('should return logs', function(done) {
  browser
      .log('browser').then(function(logs){
        console.log(logs);
      })
  ...
});
```

What I get is:

```
[ { level: 'INFO',
    message: 'https://localhost:3000/ 42:14 "foo"',
    timestamp: 1485785320222 },
  { level: 'INFO',
    message: 'https://localhost:3000/ 43:14 "bar"',
    timestamp: 1485785320222 },
  { level: 'INFO',
    message: 'https://localhost:3000/ 46:14 Array[6]',
    timestamp: 1485785320225 },
  { level: 'SEVERE',
    message: 'https://localhost:3000/favicon.ico - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)',
    timestamp: 1485785320298 } ]
```

So it should just returns a list of log entries like "foo" and "bar", so I can check if it is equal to my assumed value it should be.

I am now unsure if I need a "for..in" to build my method that I can reuse or just loop through the multiple objects and looking for logs.value.message and trim the part with "".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably easiest / most understandable to just filter for the logs that match what you're looking for:

```
it('should return logs', function(done) {
  browser
      .log('browser').then(function(logs){
        console.log(logs.filter(function (logItem) {
          return logItem.message.match(/"foo"|"bar"$/);
        });
      })
  ...
});
```

Comment: It works when I specifically want to search for "foo" or "bar" but the goal behind is to have a helper function at the end, that just returns a list of log entries, so I can work with them later.